# Show data from DataSet to TableView in MonoTouch C#

Tags: c#, dataset, xamarin.ios, tableview

I have a DataSet Object, Which is having a DataTable containing 100 rows. There are 10 Columns in the DataTable. now I want to View 5 pre selected Columns and 20 Rows in the TableView. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Each UITableView row contains a single cell.  You're going to need to create a custom UITableViewCell that can display the five values you're interested in.

Comment: I have made a class DataSource which is inheriting UITableViewSource. Now I got the Override method "UITableViewCell GetCell". In this method I have written the code for cells. Now how could I use this class? and the "GetCell" Method?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on how to use custom table cells. It is [here](http://software.tavlikos.com/2011/04/03/uitableviewcell-nib/).
You can also see in the project how to use the GetCell method, and the table view in general. Create the custom cells with interface builder. Actually, you only need one, if you display the same number of fields in each cell.